# Can we combine VALUES and SELECT queries in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am trying to insert data into a table. That table has 6 attributes, 2 of its own and 4 foreign keys.
Now I write a query like this:

```
insert into ***bus***
values ( 4 , 45 , (**select** **bus_driver**.id , **conductor**.id , **trip_location**.trip_id , **bus_route**.route_id
**from bus_driver , conductor , trip_location , bus_route**));
```

And its giving me an error like:

> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

What should I change in my query

Comment: No, you can't combine `values` and `select` like that. You can add two constant columns to your select though.

Comment: Insert into... select 4, 45, bus...

Comment: as @M.Prokhorov mentioned that is not valid syntax. You could run a query to return the values you need and assign those values to a variable and insert those values.

Comment: *from bus_driver , conductor , trip_location , bus_route* gives a recordset with a lot of records. Whereas the logic tells there must be SINGLE record.

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way 20 years ago

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the values clause and just put the select straight after the table and column names of the insert clause like below :

```
 insert into bus(column1, column2 ........) 
   select  4 , 45 , bus_driver.id , conductor.id , trip_location.trip_id , 
   bus_route.route_id from bus_driver , conductor , trip_location , bus_route;
```

Comment: I think because of the reason which I post into Q. comment.

Comment: it query return rows records they will also be inserted in the table. We can use select with insert into statement for multiple records as well.

Comment: `INSERT .. VALUES` with one data block shows that OP needs to insert only one record.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. It looks like you're going to end up with a lot of rows inserted into your `bus` table depending on the data in the other tables you're selecting from.

If you run only the select statement, see what you get for results:

```
select bus_driver.id, conductor.id, trip_location.trip_id, bus_route.route_id
from bus_driver, conductor, trip_location, bus_route
```

Then add `4, 45` in front of all those rows. That's what you'll be inserting into the `bus` table.

You may be looking to do something more like:

```
insert into bus (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6) 
   select  4, 45, bus_driver.id, conductor.id, trip_location.trip_id, bus_route.route_id 
      from bus_driver, conductor, trip_location, bus_route
      where bus_driver.column? = ?
      and conductor.column? = ?
      ...
```

And the where clauses would be constructed such that only one record is returned for each table. It depends on what you're trying to do though. There may be situations where you want more than one record from the selected tables, which would end up inserting multiple records into the `bus` table

Comment: Please, write explicitly that the condition by each table should give strictly 1 record from it in OP's case.